# Does $m(E)>0$ imply that $E$ must contain a nondegenerate interval?

Tags: real-analysis

> Does $m(E)>0$ imply that $E$ must contain a nondegenerate interval?

$E\subset\mathbb{R}.$  $m$ refers to Lebesgue measure.  $I$ refers to a nondegenerate interval.

Comment: No. Interestingly enough, though, if $m(A)>0$ then $(-a,a) \subseteq A-A$ for some $a> 0$. Where $A-A$ is the difference set of $A$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, try any [fat Cantor set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Volterra%E2%80%93Cantor_set). $ $

Answer (score 12):

For a simple counterexample, try the irrational numbers in any interval